# How to handle spring batch remote chunking in Kubernates pod?

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, spring-batch, chunking

I am trying to implement spring batch remote chunking for heavy file .
What should be ideal setup for deployment of remote chunking physically in kubernetes .
1)Can we setup worker and manager in same Kubernetes cluster and same pod can behave for manager /worker based on request ?
Or
2)Do we need to deploy  worker and manager separately in different kubernetes cluster?

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46214045/scalable-spring-batch-job-on-kubernetes

Comment: Thanks @ Mahmoud Ben hassine.  I have checked this also I was following your spring batch video to implement this . Is there any way that manager and worker run on same kubernetes clusters instead of two deployment . And in this case same pods of kubernetes  should became manager and worker simultaneously based on request Or if it will work is it ideal solution or not .  I am trying this to run as single application and expecting it works but not working with exception in local and pod . Good thing is till now that Separately manager and worker working fine in pod .

Comment: The manager and workers can run in the same cluster or different clusters. I would run them in different pods to be able to scale workers independently.

Comment: Let me try this approach.  Thanks.